# How can I get the peak and valleys of a geom_smooth line in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting some data across the year and I need to get the peaks and valleys **of the curve**, not from the dataset and then identify which is that date. How can I do that ?

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=ndvitrend)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "gam", se=FALSE) + theme_minimal() +
     scale_x_date(date_labels="%b %Y", date_breaks = "1 month") + 
     theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + theme(axis.line = element_line(color = 'black')) +
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1)) + 
     stat_peaks(span=NULL, color="red")
```

[image: peak of the dataset, not on the line]

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It's far easier to answer this type of question if we have reproducible data. However, I will recreate something that is similar to your data set:

```r
set.seed(69)

df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2019-09-01"), 
                            as.Date("2020-09-01"), by = "3 days"),
                 ndvitrend = 0.3 * sin(seq(-2, 2 * pi - 2, length.out = 123)) +
                             rnorm(123, 0.5, 0.2))
```

Now let's plot this using your code:

```r
library(ggpmisc)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = ndvitrend)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_smooth(method = "gam", se = FALSE) + 
      stat_peaks(span = NULL, color = "red") +
      theme_minimal() +
      scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y", date_breaks = "1 month") + 
      theme(plot.title  = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
            axis.line   = element_line(color = 'black'),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
g
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")'
```

[image]

You'll notice that the console told us the formula that was being used to create the smoothed line. We can therefore use that to answer your question. We need the `gam` function from package `mgcv`:

```r
library(mgcv)

df$days <- as.numeric(difftime(df$date, df$date[1], units = "day"))
model   <- gam(ndvitrend ~ s(days, bs = "cs"), data = df)
df$prediction <- predict(model)
```

So now we have stored the predictions from this model into our data frame. That should give us the identical smoothing curve that `geom_smooth` gave us:

```
g + geom_line(aes(y = prediction), data = df, 
                   size = 3, linetype = 2, col = "red")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")'
```

[image]

This is correct. Now all we need to do is find out where the peak of our prediction was:

```r
g + geom_hline(yintercept = max(df$prediction), linetype = 2)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")'
```

[image]

So we can see that our smoothed peak in this data set is

```r
max(df$prediction)
#> [1] 0.76714
```

And it occurs on:

```r
df$date[which.max(df$prediction)]
#> [1] "2020-03-20"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>